# glob() not working when using ../ alternative?

Tags: php, path, glob

Now Im farely new to the glob function and i just cant seen to get this code working, im trying to read the directory etc. etc. loop through etc. pass back to ajax. howeveri have tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` That didnt work , i tried pretty much every possible way that could be found here on stack.

```
function RenderGalleryPlugin($mid){
        $directory = "../images/ladys/".$mid."/";
        $images = glob($directory . "*.*");
        $data = "<div class=\"tj_nav\"><span id=\"tj_prev\" class=\"tj_prev\">Previous</span><span id=\"tj_next\" class=\"tj_next\">Next</span></div>";
        $data ="<div class=\"tj_wrapper\"><ul class=\"tj_gallery\">";
        var_dump($directory);
        foreach($images as $image){
            $relative_path = $directory.basename($image);
            $data .= '<li><a href=\"#\"><img src="'.$relative_path.'" /></a></li>';
        }
        $data .= "</ul></div>";
        return $data;
    }
```

I even tried to use the up one method `../` , however when i use this message something intresteing happens, the images are found but they are not being displayed,(broken path)heres what i see in chrome inspector e.g

```
<li><a href="\&quot;#\&quot;"><img src="../images/ladys/exmp5402/exmp54021_1.jpg"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> loop through etc. pass back to ajax ...

When you pass the images back through AJAX they are considered relative to the JS file that you are providing (which changes what relative path to call from completely). I would recommend using an absolute path for your images:

either:

```
<li><a href="\&quot;#\&quot;"><img src="[YOU_DOMAIN_HERE]/images/ladys/exmp5402/exmp54021_1.jpg"></a></li>
```

or:

```
<li><a href="\&quot;#\&quot;"><img src="[ABSOLUTE_PATH_FROM_DOC_ROOT]/images/ladys/exmp5402/exmp54021_1.jpg"></a></li>
```

Comment: Im testing on a local server right now i have a server but im not done constructing the site, and i have tried the http://127.0. .... method aswell as localhost but when i go about it this way the i get failed permission warnings in chrome, and not to mention the ajax call is being made from the index page not a js file inside the directory ......

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/user/"."*.*") as $filename) {
```

}

Comment: Still came back empty, p.s i already checked to make sure the dir was not empty lol.

Comment: the path is clear as day in chrome and on my local machine. idk what the problem could be....